# Error 403- When trying to retrieve single entity from Azure Table Storage using IHttpClientFactory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, azure-table-storage

Here department is PartitionKey and id is RowKey.

Error: Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.

Status Code: Forbidden

If someone could help me to resolve this error It would be great.

Thanks in advance :)

```
public HttpClient getRequestHeaders(string requestType, HttpClient Newrequest, string storageAccount, string accessKey, string resource, int Length = 0)
        {
            HttpClient Client = Newrequest;
            
            var RequestDateString = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            if (Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Contains("x-ms-date"))
                Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("x-ms-date");
            Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-date", RequestDateString);
            
            var requestUri = @"https://" + storageAccount + ".table.core.windows.net/" + resource;

            Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            if (Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Contains("x-ms-version"))
                Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("x-ms-version");

            Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-version", "2015-12-11");

            if (Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Contains("DataServiceVersion"))
                Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("DataServiceVersion");
            Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("DataServiceVersion", "3.0;NetFx");

            if (Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Contains("MaxDataServiceVersion"))
                Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("MaxDataServiceVersion");
            Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("MaxDataServiceVersion", "3.0;NetFx");


            if (Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Contains("Authorization"))
                Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("Authorization");
            var sas =  getAuthToken(Client, storageAccount, accessKey, resource);
            Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", sas);

            return Client;
        }
        
        public string getAuthToken(HttpClient request, string storageAccount, string accessKey, string resource)
        {
            try
            {
                string sAuthTokn = "";

                string stringToSign = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + "\n";

                stringToSign += "/" + storageAccount + "/" + resource;

                HMACSHA256 hasher = new HMACSHA256(Convert.FromBase64String(accessKey));

                sAuthTokn = "SharedKeyLite " + storageAccount + ":" + Convert.ToBase64String(hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign)));

                return sAuthTokn;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        public async Task<string> GetEntityByID(string department, string id)
        {
            EmployeeDetails emp = new EmployeeDetails();
            string storageAccount = "sample";
            string resourcePath = "SampleAzureTableStorage";
            string accessKey = "<sample>";
            string uri = @"https://" + storageAccount + ".table.core.windows.net/" + resourcePath + "/";
            var request = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
            request = getRequestHeaders("GET", request, storageAccount, accessKey, resourcePath);
            
            try
            {
                var httpResponseMessage = await request.GetAsync(uri + department + "/" + id);
                httpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                return await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is something I missed originally.  I am not sure what is going on in the `getAuthToken` method, BUT if you created a Shared Access Token for resource in Azure Storage, that is NOT a valid authorization token like a bearer token.  what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the reason you are getting this error is because you are using two different dates in your code.

You are getting the current date in `getRequestHeaders` method and then a different date in `getAuthToken`. This would cause the authorization header mismatch.

I would recommend modifying `getAuthToken` method and pass the date/time value computed in `getRequestHeaders` method.

Try the following code:

```
    public HttpClient getRequestHeaders(string requestType, HttpClient Newrequest, string storageAccount, string accessKey, string resource, string partitionKey, string rowKey, int Length = 0)
    {
        HttpClient Client = Newrequest;
        
        var RequestDateString = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        if (Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Contains("x-ms-date"))
            Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("x-ms-date");
        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-date", RequestDateString);
        
        var requestUri = @"https://" + storageAccount + ".table.core.windows.net/" + resource;

        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        if (Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Contains("x-ms-version"))
            Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("x-ms-version");

        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-version", "2015-12-11");

        if (Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Contains("DataServiceVersion"))
            Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("DataServiceVersion");
        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("DataServiceVersion", "3.0;NetFx");

        if (Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Contains("MaxDataServiceVersion"))
            Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("MaxDataServiceVersion");
        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("MaxDataServiceVersion", "3.0;NetFx");


        if (Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Contains("Authorization"))
            Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("Authorization");
        var sas =  getAuthToken(Client, storageAccount, accessKey, resource, RequestDateString, partitionKey, rowKey);
        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", sas);

        return Client;
    }
            
public string getAuthToken(HttpClient request, string storageAccount, string accessKey, string resource, string requestDateString, string partitionKey, string rowKey)
{
    try
    {
        string sAuthTokn = "";

        string stringToSign = requestDateString + "\n";

        stringToSign += "/" + storageAccount + "/" + resource +  "(PartitionKey='" + partitionKey + "',RowKey='" + rowKey + "')";

        HMACSHA256 hasher = new HMACSHA256(Convert.FromBase64String(accessKey));

        sAuthTokn = "SharedKeyLite " + storageAccount + ":" + Convert.ToBase64String(hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign)));

        return sAuthTokn;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}

public async Task<string> GetEntityByID(string department, string id)
{
    EmployeeDetails emp = new EmployeeDetails();
    string storageAccount = "sample";
    string resourcePath = "SampleAzureTableStorage";
    string accessKey = "<sample>";
    string uri = @"https://" + storageAccount + ".table.core.windows.net/" + resourcePath + "/";
    var request = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
    request = getRequestHeaders("GET", request, storageAccount, accessKey, resourcePath, department, id);
    
    try
    {
        var httpResponseMessage = await request.GetAsync(uri + "(PartitionKey='" + department + "',RowKey='" + id + "')");
        httpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        return await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: Still same error

Comment: What's the request URL - `var httpResponseMessage = await request.GetAsync(uri + department + "/" + id);`? It should be like `https://myaccount.table.core.windows.net/mytable(PartitionKey='<partition-key>',RowKey='<row-key>')`. Can you try that?

Comment: I tried
still same error

Comment: Found one more issue - you need to include `(PartitionKey='<partition-key>',RowKey='<row-key>')` to your `stringToSign`. I have updated the code. Please give that a try.

Comment: Can you help me with this code too I'm getting the same error and passing every header required in Authentication header

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/936599/error-403-when-trying-to-update-entity-in-azure-ta.html

Comment: It's the same issue with DateTime.UtcNow.

Comment: ReqstDateString has same value passes in above function as in this so I don't think so that's the problem

Comment: Please post the question here on Stack Overflow and I will take a look.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73075401/error-403-when-trying-to-update-entity-in-azure-table-storage-using-httpclient

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your `Authorization` header.

Here is your code:

```
Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", sas);
```

I think you should change it to:

```
Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", $"Bearer {sas}");
```

Otherwise the code looks righteous.

Comment: I don’t think so. OP is using shared key authorization and not Azure AD based authorization.

Comment: @Glenn Ferrie  
After trying this now I'm getting 
Status code: 400 "Authentication information is not given in the correct format. Check the value of Authorization header."

Comment: @KanchanKausal as per MDN documentation, you need to identify the authorization scheme in your authorization header - link to docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization